What is a Wronskian and why is it useful here?
A particle in the region $z$ is described by $\psi(z, p)=A(p) f(z, p)$. Where $A(p)$ is independent of $z$ and $f(z,p)$ is the solution to:
\begin{equation}
\left[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}+\frac{p^2}{\hbar^2}-\frac{2 m}{\hbar^2} U(z)\right] f(z,p)=0
\end{equation}
Solutions to the above equation are a form of superposition of two linearly independent solutions which are determined from the boundary conditions. The solution $\psi(z, p)=A(p) f(z, p)$ may be written in the form
$$
A(p) f(z, p)=M \varphi_1(z, p)+N \varphi_2(z, p)
$$
where $M$ and $N$ are coefficients independent of $z$. For equations that do not contain the first derivative, we may assume that one of the solutions $\phi_{1}$ equals zero at $z = 0$.
This is now where I struggle: writing down the Wronskian $W$ from the left-hand and right-hand sides of the above equation the above equation we obtain:
$$
A(p) W\left(\varphi_1, f\right)=N W\left(\varphi_1, \varphi_2\right) \quad 
$$
where
$$
W\left(\varphi_1, \varphi_2\right) \equiv \varphi_1 \frac{\partial \varphi_2}{\partial z}-\varphi_2 \frac{\partial \varphi_1}{\partial z}
$$
Why is $A(p) W\left(\varphi_1, f\right)=N W\left(\varphi_1, \varphi_2\right) $ true? Why is it useful?

Why are you computing the Wronskian?
